TextView not initialized even though it is
I am loosing my mind on this one. I am getting error saying "Variable 'joiningDate' might not have been initialized". Here is the code:
private TextView joiningDate;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_registration);
        joiningDate = findViewById(R.id.joiningDate);
    }

private void saveData() {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
        String userId = editTextUserId.getText().toString();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String joiningDate = joiningDate.getText().toString();

        // Now send this data to your server
        sendDataToServer(name, email, phone, userId, password, joiningDate);
    }

Please help me fix it.

You are using same name for the string as the textview. Use a different name instead of joiningDate
String joinDate = joiningDate.getText().toString();


It was so simple I feel kinda stupid now. Thanks though, I was really struggling.

It's Ok. It happens to best of us.

String variable and EditText are same name that's why the error occurs. change the string variable name.
